# On Android, react navigation won't navigate away if there's an ongoing request. How to fix this?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

As titled.

Weird thing is that this doesn't happen on both Pixel simulator. Only on my OPPO phone.

If there's an ongoing request in the background, I can only scroll, but hitting back, opening modal, nothing. And it will eventually trigger once the request is completed.

I've tried to listen to 'beforeRemove' event, but it's also just triggered when the request is done. I mean, if can use this, I just cancel the axios request and call it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because the navigation between screens is performed by the JS thread and the as you know indeed the network requests are performed with the JS thread as well, that's why you need to try the [react native screens library](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens) in order to take advantage of native navigation, and offload the JS thread for this matter.

I hope my answer helps you solve your problem.

Comment: I just tested it, but still the problem persist. Although I'm not sure I've installed it correctly, all I did was install the lib, and changed to`super.onCreate(null);` in MainActivity.java. that;s it?

Comment: use need to import enableScreens from RN screens `import {enableScreens} from 'react-native-screens'` in App.(js|tsx) and then call this method with true in params in App.js as well:
`enableScreens(true);`

Comment: Apologies for the late response, was on leave for a week. However, I just tried that, doesn't help.